# python3 replace &#39; in a string

Tags: string, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to clean text strings containing any `'` or `&#39` (which includes an `;` but if i add it here you will see just `&#39;` again. Because the the ANSI is also encoded by stackoverflow. The string content contains `&#39;` and when it does there is an error.

when i insert the string to my database i get this error:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "s"
>   LINE 1: ...tment and has commenced a search for mr. whitnell's

the original string looks like this:

`...a search for mr. whitnell&#39s...`

To remove the `'` and `&#39 ;` I use:

```
stripped_content = stringcontent.replace("'","")

stripped_content = stringcontent.replace("&#39 ;","")
```

any advice is welcome, best regards

Comment: thanks now i understand how i can get that part to be unformatted in the stackoverflow post;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to `replace("&#39 ;","")` it literally searching for `"&#39 ;"` occurrences in string. You need to convert  `"&#39 ;"` to its character equivalent. Try this:

```
s = "That's how we 'roll"
r = s.replace(chr(int('&#39'[2:])), "")
```

and with this `chr(int('&#39'[2:]))` you'll get `'` character.

```
Output:

Thats how we roll
```

**Note**
If you try to run this `s.replace(chr(int('&#39'[2:])), "")` **without** saving your result in variable then your original `string` would not be affected.

Comment: interesting will check it out

Comment: Hi i tried the example and got the following results:
    t = "Diner at John's at 9 o'clock"
    t.replace(chr(int('&#39'[2:])), "")
    print("example 1:", t)
    t.replace("'","")
    print("example 2:", t)

console output:
phase 1: Diner at John's at 9 o'clock
phase 2: Diner at John's at 9 o'clock

Comment: Input: `t= "Diner at John's at 9 o'clock"`, then you need to **save** the result as **t=** `t.replace(chr(int('&#39'[2:])), "") ` and the output will be correct.

Comment: thanks for your help. I should have seen that last one :)